# How to remove content inside {{ }} from string - PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like

```
$data = "{{quickbar | image=Baby Beach Aruba.JPG | caption=Baby Beach | location=LocationAruba.png | flag=Flag of Aruba.svg | capital=Oranjestad | government=parliamentary democracy | currency=Aruban guilder/florin (AWG) | area=193 sq km | population=71,891 (July 2006 est.) | language=Dutch (official), Papiamento (a creole of Spanish, Portuguese, and Dutch origin), English (widely spoken), Spanish | religion=Roman Catholic 82%, Protestant 8%, Hindu, Muslim, Confucian, Jewish | electricity=120V/60Hz (North American plug) | callingcode=+297 | tld=.aw | timezone=UTC -4 }} Aruba [1] is a Caribbean island 15 miles north of the coast of Venezuela. The island is an autonomous dependency of the Kingdom of the Netherlands.";
```

I want to remove all contents inside {{}} and that brackets also

I am expecting like this

```
$data = "Aruba [1] is a Caribbean island 15 miles north of the coast of Venezuela. The island is an autonomous dependency of the Kingdom of the Netherlands.";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If those brackets can't ever be nested, it's simple:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\{\{.*?\}\}\s*/s', '', $subject);
```

If they can, you need a recursive regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\{\{(?:(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)*+|(?R))+\}\}\s*/', '', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
{{          # Match {{
(?:         # Either match...
 (?:        # the following regex:
  (?!{{|}}) # Unless we're at the string {{ or }},
  .         # match any character
  )*+       # any number of times (possessively to avoid backtracking).
 |          # Or match...
 (?R)       # whatever this entire regex matches (recursively)
)+          # End of alternation, repeat as necessary
}}          # Match }}
\s*         # Match optional trailing whitespace
```

See it on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/kW7eL5).

Comment: Thanks..It is working for above example. But for this text it is not working    {{quickbar | image=Baby Beach Aruba.JPG | caption=Baby Beach | location=LocationAruba.png | flag=Flag of Aruba.svg | capital=Oranjestad | government=parliamentary democracy | currency=Aruban guilder/florin (AWG) | area=193 sq km | population=71,891 (July 2006 est.) | language=Dutch (official), Papiamento (a creole of Spanish, | electricity=120V/60Hz (North American plug) | callingcode=+297 | tld=.aw | timezone=UTC -4 }} Aruba is a Caribbean island 15 miles north of the coast of Venezuela.

Comment: @FrancisMV123: I'm assuming that there is a newline somewhere in that text? Then you need the `/s` modifier, because without it, the dot will not match newlines. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$data = "this is {{ remove }} a {{ remove }} sample {{ remove }} text";
echo $data = preg_replace("/\{\{[^}]+\}\}/", "", $data); //this is a sample text
?>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, too, although it will fail if single `}`s are present between double `{{/}}`s.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes, I think user should change the design to avoid regex replacement for complex patterns...

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$data = "this is {{ remove }} a {{ remove }} sample {{ remove }} text";
echo preg_replace('/(\{\{)[^\{]*(\}\})/', '', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex if it isn't necessary.

```
$data = "{{quickbar | image=Baby Beach Aruba.JPG | caption=Baby Beach | location=LocationAruba.png | flag=Flag of Aruba.svg | capital=Oranjestad | government=parliamentary democracy | currency=Aruban guilder/florin (AWG) | area=193 sq km | population=71,891 (July 2006 est.) | language=Dutch (official), Papiamento (a creole of Spanish, Portuguese, and Dutch origin), English (widely spoken), Spanish | religion=Roman Catholic 82%, Protestant 8%, Hindu, Muslim, Confucian, Jewish | electricity=120V/60Hz (North American plug) | callingcode=+297 | tld=.aw | timezone=UTC -4 }} Aruba [1] is a Caribbean island 15 miles north of the coast of Venezuela. The island is an autonomous dependency of the Kingdom of the Netherlands.";
$data = implode('', array_map(function($a) { // Pass substring to array_map()
    $a = explode("}}", $a); // Split substring into array at boundaries of }}
    return $a[count($a) - 1]; // The last index of this array contains your content. The others contain the contents starting at {{ and ending at }}
}, explode("{{", $data))); // Split string into array of substrings at boundaries of {{
print_r($data);
```

Outputs:

> Aruba [1] is a Caribbean island 15 miles north of the coast of
>   Venezuela. The island is an autonomous dependency of the Kingdom of
>   the Netherlands.

This function will work for any number of those brackets.